# A better solution to replace an old cursor?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables like this

table1 sorted by paymentid, paydate:

```
 paymentid   paydate   amount

  1         20120101    100

  1         20120101    150

  1         20120101    150

  2         20120115    100

  2         20120115    100

...
```

table2 sorted by paymentid, paydate:

```
paymentid    paydate   pay1   pay2   pay3....base on the position from table1...up to pay20

1            20120101   null  null    null   

2            20120115   null  null    null

...
```

after update, table2 should be like this

```
1            20120101   100   100     150   null.....

2            20120115   100   100     null  null    null.....
```

The possible solutions i can come up so far are:

1, a temp table for looping thru table1

2, a cursor...current solution:

```
declare @paymentid int 

declare @paydate   char(10)

declare @amount    money

declare @count int

declare @saveid int

declare @savedate char(10)

delcare cur cursor for select paymentid, paydate, amount from table1 order by paymentid, paydate

open cur



fetch next from cur into @paymentid,@paydate,@amount

while @@fetch_status = 0

  if @saveid <> @paymentid or @savedate <> @paydate

     set @count = 1

     set @saveid = @paymentid

     set @savedate = @paydate

  else set @count = @count + 1

  if @count = 1

  update table2 

  set pay1 = @amount

  where paymentid = @paymentid and paydate = @paydate

  if @count = 2

  update table2 

  set pay2 = @amount

  ...

  fetch next

  ...
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What are the values out of table one supposed to be sorted by? Also, I assume you mean 100 150 150 in row 1 of the final result?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. table1 sorted by paymentid, paydate. the finial result of table2 will have one row for any same paymentid&paydate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! FYI, you just inadvertently overrode an edit suggested by someone who was trying to assist you with formatting. There's a help page for that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and a smaller one built right into the editor that you can access with the bright orange "?" icon at the top right of the box.

Comment: What I meant was, how do we know that the order of values in the first row is 100, 150, 150, NULL, NULL... and not NULL, 150, 100, NULL, 150...?

Comment: @Sebastian, sorry for the confusing. I tried to edit my original post by adding the current cursor coding, but have a hard time to save it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50f69/11)

```
declare @Test Table (paymentid int, 
                   paydate varchar(25), amount int)


INSERT INTO @Test

SELECT 1,'20120101',100
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'20120101',150
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'20120101',150
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'20120115',100
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'20120115',100

--INSERT into Table2 //insert here
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, 'pay' + CAST(Row_Number() OVER (Partition by paymentid, 
                        paydate order by amount) AS VARCHAR) PayCol
FROM @Test
)  V
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(Amount) For PayCol IN 
   (pay1,pay2,pay3,pay4, pay5, pay6, pay7, pay8, pay9, pay10,
        pay11,pay12,pay13,pay14, pay15, pay16, pay17, pay18, pay19, pay20)
) As P
```